# How to merge overlapping instances in geometry nodes?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, instances

*I'm still new to geometry nodes for some years using blender, I'm trying to make a cool transition effect, but I have this problem of overlapping instances
Keep in mind that it's animated!
Also be sure to explain as clear as you can and make it short and simple! I have autism, and I have trouble understanding long walls of text! Provide image steps too!*

> **What I have :**

[image: What I Have]

> **My Nodes :**

[image: My nodes]

> **What I want to achieve (Edited with Adobe Photoshop) :**

[image: What I want to achieve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the type of mesh (unfortunately this is not clearly visible here), the only node available to you for this is the `Mesh Boolean` node (choose the option *Union*). This essentially works like the `Boolean` modifier.

This is the only node in Geometry Nodes that has the ability to merge meshes.

Alternatively, you could simply use the `Join Geometry` node and achieve the desired visual impression with a shader.

> Tip: In your specific case, however, you might need to apply the `Realize Instances` node first, so that the instances are translated into a mesh.

Comment: I have never seen that node, since I am new to geometry nodes do you know where to connect it? I tried connecting it to something but it froze blender

Comment: Depending on the result you want you could also use a remesh modifier, directly after the geo-node modifier.

Comment: @BeeAPotato You can find the node in the category "Mesh", but only starting with Blender v3+ https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/mesh_boolean.html

Comment: @jst-kiko I tried the remesh modifier and fiddled around but I get no result, maybe because I forgot to say these meshes are Planes

Comment: @quellenform I have found the node but I'm wondering where to put it, either I replace the "Join Geometry" or something else

Comment: Try this order: `Realize Instances` > `Mesh Boolean` (for each plane, because you cannot merge vertices of a plane which are on different Z-positions!)

Comment: @quellenform it worked for the black squares but not for the outline, It also froze blender again :').

Comment: Update, removed the outline which was just another pane edited with a bevel cut in it, and tried `Add` > `Grease Pencil` > `Object Line Art` however it seems that the lines overlap still

Comment: Update : I found  get around! (almost) |

I created a second pane (named `Pane.002` because I've been lazy to rename my objects :D), used inset faces to cut a hole, then assign a the newly created face to the transparent material! : https://imgur.com/HNmNaEs |


I also edited my Geo nodes! : https://imgur.com/sjLDjRY


| Result : https://imgur.com/CnTQmOI

| One small problem, I seem to get these undesirable overlaps and black parts : https://imgur.com/x42pIVG

| This question will still be open if it's possible to fix it!

Comment: @BeeAPotato I think that the question "How to merge overlapping instances in geometry nodes?" (with geometry nodes) has actually already been answered. In your specific case, it might be good if you share your blend file so someone can go into more detail about your specific problem, or you post a new question.

Comment: It's alright I'll search for questions later, for now I'm happy with what I got

Thanks guys for the help~!

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could possibly find is using the
*Mesh to Volume* node with *Volume to Mesh*.

It doesn't bring perfect results, but it is the closest I can get.